# Oracle SQL join query

Tags: sql, oracle, join

```
TABLEA
LOGIN_ID ,COL1,COL2

TABLEB
LOGIN_ID, RESIGN_DATE, LAST_DATE, STATUS
```

I want to select the login_id,resign_date and last_date for a particular login_id from TABLEA

Login_ID is the link between TABLEA and TABLEB. In TABLEB there can be multiple records for same login_id. i want to select the resign_date and last_date which will satisfy the below conditions.

```
1)if status is null for at least one of them
    it should identify that entry whose status is null
    System populate the resign_date and last_date of this entry 
2)if status is ‘Y’ for all of them
      resign_date = ’12/31/2050’ 
      last_date = ’12/31/2050’
3)If no entry in TABLEB
    resign_date = null
    last_date = null
```

How to write an oracle sql query for this??

Comment: :How system will populate the date for null entry ...what date will it be ? i am asking about first condition

Comment: What if there is more than one TABLEB row with status null?

Comment: @GauravSoni in that case i should get the resign_date and last_date of the entry whose status is null..

Comment: @TonyAndrews there will be only one row with status null.. i forgot to mention it..

Comment: @Ollie i tried to write it using left join...I was not able to make it working..

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Oracle 9i rel 2 or later, this should work...

```
with c  as (select * from tableb where status is null)

select * 
from tablea
left join 
(
        select login_id, resign_date, last_date from c
        union
        select login_id, '12/31/2050', '12/31/2050' from tableb 
                where login_id not in (select login_id from c)
) d on tablea.login_Id = d.login_Id
```

I'm assuming that status is either Y or null in tableB

Answer (score 0):

You can use [analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm) to do this, which has the advantage of only hitting each table once.

```
select distinct a.login_id,
    case when b.login_id is null then null
        when first_value(b.status) over (partition by b.login_id
            order by b.status nulls first) is null then b.resign_date
        when first_value(b.status) over (partition by b.login_id
            order by b.status nulls first) = 'Y' then date '2050-12-31'
    end as resign_date,
    case when b.login_id is null then null
        when first_value(b.status) over (partition by b.login_id
            order by b.status nulls first) is null then b.last_date
        when first_value(b.status) over (partition by b.login_id
            order by b.status nulls first) = 'Y' then date '2050-12-31'
    end as last_date
from tablea a
left join tableb b on b.login_id = a.login_id
order by a.login_id;
```

The relevant part is the `case` statement - there are two but they are the same, apart from which column is returned from `TABLEB`. The case has three clauses:

```
when b.login_id is null then null
```

If there are no matching records in `TABLEB`, because of the outer join `B.LOGIN_ID` will be null; this matches your third criteria.

```
when first_value(b.status) over (partition by b.login_id
    order by b.status nulls first) is null then b.resign_date
```

The `first_value()` function returns the 'lowest' status value, and the `nulls first` means that if any of the matching `TABLEB` records has a null status, that's what will be seen first. So this matches your first criteria, and uses `TABLEB.RESIGN_DATE` for that null-status row.

```
when first_value(b.status) over (partition by b.login_id
    order by b.status nulls first) = 'Y' then date '2050-12-31'
```

Same as the previous clause, but this time if the first value is `Y` then there can't be any nulls, because of the `nulls first` again. (This is assuming that the status can only ever be `null` or 'Y', which your question implies - if there are any other statuses then the behaviour isn't specified in your criteria). So if all the matching rows in `TABLEB` have status `Y`, this uses the fixed date value, which matches your second criteria.

Note that I've used a [date literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm#sthref363) here; if you prefer you could use `to_date('12/31/2050', 'MM/DD/YYYY')`, but don't use implicit conversion and assume a particular date mask will be in play.